# What's the performance penalty of using isKindOfClass in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, performance

I'm considering introducing:

```
if ([myInstance isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]) { do something...}
```

into a piece of code that gets called pretty often.  Will I introduce a significant performance penalty?  In Objective C, is there a quicker way of assessing whether a given object instance is of certain class type?  For example, is the following quicker?  (I realize the test is somewhat different)

```
if (myInstance.class == [SomeClass class]) { do something else...}
```

Comment: What did the results of your profiling tell you?

Comment: I haven't done any profiling yet; that's my next step.  I was hoping to find some documentation that explains the underlying magic for classes in Objective C before jumping into blind perf testing.  However, I haven't found anything so I'm going to just try different permutations next.  Any suggestions on how else I could identify a class type of a given instance?

Comment: There's no such thing as blind performance testing...  only blind optimization!  Also, the Obj-C runtime decides which method to call based on the object's class every time you call a method, so take advantage of that by putting the { do something...} in a method on the class you're interested in.

Comment: I disagree.  You can be much more effective in your testing if you have at least a clue as to what's going on underneath.  I, unfortunately, don't.  Also, codewarrior, while your observation about type polymorphism is generally correct, it doesn't apply in my situation.  I cache method pointers for an often-called list of methods and I need to refresh those pointers when my list contains instances of multiple types.  Needless to say, I'm playing with some numbers now.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The Obj-C runtime caches the most frequently used method pointers for you. Read this: http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-3.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way to see if two objects are of the same class is to compare their `isa` pointers. However, this means you'll miss when one object's class is a subclass of the other object's class, which is exactly what `isKindOfClass:` is meant for.

Regardless, the optimization you're talking about has already been done here:

http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-3-imp-deluxe.html

Comment: That's exactly the type of info I was looking for.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: Someone told me Apple doesn't want you using `isa` pointers directly anymore.

Comment: The equality check with `==` in the question is more equivalent to `isMemberOfClass:` which does not take subclasses into account.